# Trouble installing Nvidia drivers because of the disabled secure boot

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, bios, secure-boot

I need to update my Nvidia drivers in `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS`, but while installing drivers using below command

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-410
```

I am getting this message

```
...
Secure Boot not enabled on this system
...
```

I tried to enable the secure boot from `BIOS` but I am stuck with this error

[image]

Actually recently I have updated my BIOS as I was upgrading my CPU, I think after updating the BIOS some settings have been changed

I am not an advanced user, this is the first time I came across this issue and I don’t want to mess up with the BIOS settings, can anyone help me resolve this issue

Motherboard: [Asrock B360M Pro 4](https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/B360M%20Pro4/index.asp)

> Note: I also have Windows 10 installed on other SSD and it works fine, I have installed all the drivers and benchmarked it without any problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out problem was something else, I left secure boot disabled. Actually after installing `Nvidia driver` I was also installing `CUDA` toolkit which has some built in old Nvidia drivers, so while installing CUDA Nvidia drivers was getting corrupted. Hence first I installed Nvidia driver then installed CUDA by not allowing it to install Nvidia drivers and the problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

(Before you continue: make sure you have an external copy ("backup") of all precious things on your computer.)

There is probably no need to enable secure boot.

You can try removing the shim-signed package like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove shim-signed
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-410
```

You will need to reboot before the driver is loaded in Ubuntu.

Comment: Hello @Gogowitsch, Is this command safe to run

Comment: @Atinesh From my experience it is safe to run, if secure boot is currently disabled in your BIOS.